# outlook - ignore mail doesn't work when there is a rule which move mail to a folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

#### Steps:

1. Create a rule, which move mail with some condition to a folder
2. Ignore a thread mail which fit with rule in #1

#### Expect

The mail in that thread should be auto deleted

#### Problem

The mail will be moved to folder (in #1) instead of being deleted

The mail come from internal company so it's not kind of spam, I just don't care about that thread, but still need to care about other mails from those people. How could I make the ignore feature work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule which moves mail with some condition to a folder has option ***stop processing more rules*** checked. So when a mail is processed with this rule it prevents other ruler to process it again. Option is marked **red** on the picture below.

[image]

But you should create just one rule that deletes emails that contains the thing you don't care about. Option is marked **green** on the picture above.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will config my rules to not "stop processing more rules" and check if it works. 
P/S: I can't create rule to delete "those things I don't care about", because it doesn't have conventions :'(

Comment: @Luke You are welcome. But how do you know which emails to move to that "ignore folder"?

Comment: Can everything work fine after unchecking  "stop processing more rules". I tests similar issue in my Outlook and it could work fine without any issues. Besides, Outlook ignore feature will only removes all messages related to the conversation that you select. Please check if the messages are in the same conversation.

Comment: @Luke Did my answer helped you?

Comment: @JeffYang7 I don't have "ignore folder", I'm trying to use outlook's feature "Ignore mail" to ignore some mail thread that i don't want to care about